# Parsing a comma separated string in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to parse a comma separated string with Common lisp with the function below. For `(separate-on-comma "a,b,c")` I would expect the output `("a" "b" "c")` but instead I get `("c" "c" "c")`.
What do I miss here?

```
(defun separate-on-comma (line)
    (loop
       with fields = () 
       with field = (make-array 0 :element-type 'character :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0)
       for x across line
       when (char= x #\,)        
       do (push field fields)
       and do (setf (fill-pointer field) 0)
       else
       do (vector-push-extend x field)
       finally 
     (push field fields)
     (return fields)))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Alternative: use the `split-sequence` library.  Alternative implementation: use `position` and `subseq` in a loop.

Comment: > (ql:quickload :split-sequence)
> (split-sequence:split-sequence #\, "a,b,c")
("a" "b" "c")

Comment: `(progn (ql:quickload "cl-ppcre") (cl-ppcre:split "," "a,b,c"))
>("a" "b" "c") `
Now you can even use regexps for splitting a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working only with one *field* array. That's okay. But you better copy it when you push it to the `fields` list variable. Use `copy-seq`.

Alternatively create a new field array once you pushed the old one onto the fields list.